# How to judge long variable is null, or can if() contain an exception judgment in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement, exception, long-integer

In my case, `results[i]` might not exist in HBase table, so using `getTimestamp()` to get `results[i]'s` timestamp might cause an exception. Timestamp in HBase is a long variable, so following two ways I tried do not works.

```
if((results[i].listCells().get(0).getTimestamp()) != null){
    rowkeytime = results[i].listCells().get(0).getTimestamp();
}

if(((Long)(results[i].listCells().get(0).getTimestamp())) != null){
    rowkeytime = results[i].listCells().get(0).getTimestamp();
}
```

I want to know whether there is an usage like below in Java?

```
if ((results[i].listCells().get(0).getTimestamp()) throws an exception){
    rowkeytime = results[i].listCells().get(0).getTimestamp();
}
```

Comment: the `throws an exception` is working with `try`-`catch`...

Comment: You probably need to check if the `.get(0)` part is `!= null` (or maybe the `results[i]`). The timestamp is a `long` variable and it can't be `null` (`null` is for objects, not for basic type variables as `long`)

Comment: Why do you use `results[i].listCells().get(0).getTimestamp()` to check if `results[i]` exists? Are you iterating over all possible `i`s? Why can't you determine the correct range of indicies?

Comment: If you're saying that `results[i]` might not exist, then you should check whether `results[i] != null`.

Comment: results[i] comes from input strings, so it won't be null in this case, but the string probably  not be in the HBase table,  so it is probably without a timestamp.   Beginner in Java, sorry for not describing clearly. Thanks for all your help~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `try-catch` to handle exceptions:

```
try {
    results[i].listCells().get(0).getTimestamp();
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    // Do something if an exception is thrown
}
```

In your scenario it would be better to check you input beforehand.

```
if (results != null && results.length >= i - 1) {
    results[i].listCells().get(0).getTimestamp();
    // You may want to add additional checks for
    // the return values of listCells() and get(0)
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to `catch (Exception etc ...`, rather, catch more specific exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

> ***...in my case, results[i] might not exist...***

is you mean **results[i]** can be null then it would be good to check whether the reference is pointing to null or not,

this will be done as:

```
results[i] == null
```

that returns true is your results[i] is null,